# Allow Only One Selection On CheckListView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFx project and am using the control `CheckListView`

Is there a way to code this so that the control allows the user to only select **ONE** option from the `checklistview`

Comment: What's a `CheckListView`? This isn't part of the standard library. Also, wouldn't this be functionally equivalent to a standard list view with single selection mode set on the selection model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
    checkListView.getCheckModel().getCheckedIndices().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                 // disable the rest of the cells
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: most problably (assuming that "disable" involves unchecking the others) that's wrong: it's not allowed to change the state of a list in its listChangeListener.